# Are events not inherited in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I have a contract A, which is inherited by B (in other words, contract B is A).

I have an event in contract A, "Registration", but I wasn't able to listen for the event/get past events.

In the ABI for contract B, I don't see that event listed. Are events not inherited in Ethereum or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they are.
The following code will perfectly work:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.19;

contract A {
    event LOG(uint _num);
}

contract B is A {
    function doSomething() public{
        LOG(3);
    }
}
```

Also, this is the ABI of contract B, which as you can see does contain the event:

[image]

Comment: You're right, I was having some sort of issue with Truffle compile, it wasn't updating my compiled contracts correctly. Deleting everything in /build/contracts and recompiling provided the correct ABI, thank you.